# Why is this simple async - promise - reduce code is working?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, reduce

Why this code is working perfect? I don't know why this code working.

The loop method returns nothing, so accumulator needs to be null and this code must not work.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  const awaitFunc = (val) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('awaitFunc', val);
   resolve();
 }, 500);
  });
  
  const start = async () => {
    console.log('start');

    await arr.reduce(async (promise, val, index) => {
      await promise;

      console.log('reduce loop', val);
      
      await awaitFunc(val);
    }, Promise.resolve());

    console.log('end');
  };

  start();
```

result seems like this.

```
start
reduce loop 1
(500ms)
awaitFunc 1
reduce loop 2
(500ms)
awaitFunc 2
reduce loop 3
(500ms)
awaitFunc 3
reduce loop 4
(500ms)
awaitFunc 4
end
```

Comment: a) an `async function` always returns a promise b) the `await`s would handle `null`/`undefined` just fine

Comment: Btw, please don't use `reduce` for sequential iteration when you have `async`/`await` at hand - just write a `for … of` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` function automatically returns a Promise. If the function contains `await`s, the Promise will resolve once all `await`s have finished (and the interpreter reaches the bottom of the function block). Because the accumulator is an `async` function, it automatically returns a Promise, so `await`ing the resolution of the Promise returned by the *last* iteration (the last run of the accumulator) makes sense.

So, the

```
 await arr.reduce(async (promise, val, index) => {
   await promise;

   console.log('reduce loop', val);

   await awaitFunc(val);
 }, Promise.resolve());
```

is equivalent to

```
await arr.reduce((promise, val, index) => {
  return promise.then(() => {
    console.log('reduce loop', val);
    return awaitFunc(val);
    // ^^^^^^^ returned end of Promise chain, so accumulator promise in next reduce loop will resolve
    // once above promise resolves
  });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

or

```
 await arr.reduce((promise, val, index) => {
   // just for illustration, don't use the explicit Promise construction antipattern
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
     // await promise;
     promise.then(() => {
       console.log('reduce loop', val);
       // await awaitFunc(val);
       awaitFunc(val).then(resolve)
       //                  ^^^^^^^ Accumulator promise in next reduce loop will resolve
     });
   });
 }, Promise.resolve());
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const awaitFunc = (val) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('awaitFunc', val);
    resolve();
  }, 500);
});

const start = async () => {
  console.log('start');

   await arr.reduce((promise, val, index) => {
     // just for illustration, don't use the explicit Promise construction antipattern
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       // await promise;
       promise.then(() => {
         console.log('reduce loop', val);
         // await awaitFunc(val);
         awaitFunc(val).then(resolve)
       });
     });
   }, Promise.resolve());

  console.log('end');
};

start();
```